# Check if String contain only 2 numbers separated by 1 comma in Java

Tags: java, string, validation, netbeans, integer

I need to validate the lines of an input. But each line can only contain 2 numbers separated by 1 comma. Example of format:

1,4

2,7

8,9

Also the first number must be under a certain max (my program checks the max value possible by a id.size() method, it gives the size of a list and that must be the maximum number possible for the first number of the string).

Second number can be any value.

Comment: Alright...post the code which you have tried so far.

Comment: Firstly, split it on a comma, and count the parts (taking care to ensure you handle trailing commas correctly); then parse the two parts to ints, and check them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to validate that you have two numbers separated by a comma, if you are only working with integers.

```
if(str.matches("-?[0-9]+,-?[0-9]+")){
 //valid
} else {
 //invalid
}
```

After that, you can use `String#split` along with `Integer.parseInt` to get the two numbers.

```
final String[] parts = str.split(",");
final int num1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
final int num2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
if(num1 < MAX_VALUE_FOR_FIRST_NUM){
   //valid
} else {
  //invalid; display error message
}
```

Comment: This did the job perfectly, but its missing to check multilines, how do i allow it to be \n at the end too? i need it to work with bot one-line and multi-line. My method has this parameter method("Num1,Num2\nNum1,Num2) beacause it support multilines inside the code.

Comment: @JavierJerez You can use `.split("\n")` and parse each line separately.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for getting both numbers (s is input string):

```
int first=Integer.parseInt(s.split(",")[0].trim().replace("(", ""));
int second=Integer.parseInt(s.split(",")[1].trim().replace(")", ""));
```

This will get you number and get rid of `(` and `)`. You should use this for each line that you enter.
For checking did input has more numbers use this:

```
if(s.split(",").length>2){
    //show some error
}
```

After this you only need to check numbers for min and max value for them.

Comment: Yeah that's correct

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to check if the line you have contains 2 numbers and one comma, and then you have to check if the two substrings that the comma makes are digits. So the code you want is the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Enter String: ");
    String line = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);

    int max_number = 100;
    int firstNumber = 0, secondNumber = 0;
    if (line.contains(",")) {
        if(isNumeric(line.substring(0,line.indexOf(","))) && isNumeric(line.substring(line.indexOf(",")+1))){
            firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0,line.indexOf(",")));
            secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(line.indexOf(",")+1));
        }

    }

    if(firstNumber <= max_number){
        System.out.println("FirstNumber: " + firstNumber + " SecondNumber: " + secondNumber);
    }

}

public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the two numbers using Regular Expression and then check the max condition for the number.

```
String regex = "^(-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input); // input as 1,4

if (matcher.find()) {
    int num1 = matcher.group(1));
    int num2 = matcher.group(2));
    
    if (num1 == id.size()) {
        // some logic
    }
    
    // some more logic
}
```